# How to get an Email alert from linux server, when any file updated

Tags: linux, perl, centos

I am having dedicated centos server, and one of my site got hacked.

So please anyone help for this security issues.

I need to get an email alert if anyone updated or created php file in my server for last 24 hours.

Is there any perl script to do this job as well as any cron job codes.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 2):

Intrusion detection:

**Tripwire**: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8758

**auditd**: You could use linux auditing subsystem: http://www.linuxscrew.com/2012/07/04/track-file-changes-auditd/ .Use aureport to get the information stored here.

Realtime monitoring:

**inotify**: You could use inotify to watch file change on the fly:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html 
http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/04/native-file-system-watcher-for-linux/
http://sourceforge.net/projects/iwatch/

**gamin**: Based on this: http://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/